# Build an Vue app based on modules that may be missing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, build, module, vite

I writing module-based Vue+Vite app and i got few Vue components and some app thats actually works, but the thing is some of components may be missing but app should be work without them. How can i make sure that modules that don't exist are not imported or used.

For example i can delete some side bar or footer and they should just won't render.

Maybe should create the wrapper of all components that dynamically importing actual module and if it's not exist then wrapper returns nothing?

Comment: do you mean some '*.vue' files are missing? SFC files?

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev yes, some ".vue" files. Or actually it's can be JSX content. The goal is make app work without some modules and i can store files in any form i guess.

Comment: It's not clear why you want this, maybe there could be more cleaner and appropriate solution. could you explain?

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I know, but task is task. The idea is write whole application and install it to multiple users then just remove some components that not allowed for specific user. I could do role managment but the thing is app building all modules and the bundle contains all modules anyway what shouldn't be in my case by specific reasons

Comment: You can't do this. .vue aren't spec-compliant and cannot be recognized by a browser. Means that you need to have all modules you expect to use at build time. You can build multiple sub-apps and make plugin apps to communicate with main one to register optional components. Also check "module federation" for dynamic modules

Comment: it's simple, done, enjoy

Comment: @EstusFlask you are wrong, the task is solved with a rollup hook

Comment: @EstusFlask let's the OP decide whether my solution works for him rather than blindly downvote, otherwise rather rude behavior from your side

Comment: If you need a source code I can provide

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I'm not the only person who reads this question and I didn't downvote your answer. It's a hacky approach but not bad. But this looks like a solution to XY problem though. There are no legit reasons for the comps to not exist in a repo where they are expected, "remove some components that not allowed for specific user" is a very blunt approach for role-based or modular system

Comment: @EstusFlask unfortunately in the most cases an OP doesn't care about a better approaches to the problem. if you suggest a better solution it's often rejected. so if one wants an accepted answer there's no choice but provide what the OP wants. about hacky - imho it's not a hack, it's an official rollup hook. it would be hacky if it's some workaround outside the officially supported hooks

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev It's hacky because it's a fix for a problem that could be solved in a more coherent way and is applied to unspecified set of modules. This at least can cause errors in ide because it potentially uses a different mechanism to resolve modules (jsconfig, etc)

Comment: @EstusFlask the OP asked for a hack, a hack is given :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy to solve this with a rollup plugin. The plugin could be written right inside `vite.config.js`. Here you use the rollup hook `resolveId`. The Vite/Rollup calls this hook when it cannot resolve an import. If it's a Vue SFC you resolve it to any placeholder component of choice:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        {
            resolveId(id) {
                if (id.endsWith('.vue')) {
                    return './src/components/Placeholder.vue';
                }
            },
        }
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
    }
})
```

App.vue with some non-existing component:

```
<script setup>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import TheWelcome from './components/TheWelcome.vue'
import MissingComponent from './components/MissingComponent.vue'
</script>

<template>
    <header>
        <img alt="Vue logo" class="logo" src="./assets/logo.svg" width="125" height="125" />

        <div class="wrapper">
            <HelloWorld msg="You did it!" />
            <MissingComponent />
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <TheWelcome />
    </main>
</template>
```

src/components/Placeholder.vue (if you want it empty just do `<template></template>`):

```
<template>
    That's a placeholder for missing component, could be empty...
</template>
```

Result:

[image]

The only problem is that HMR doesn't work if you change the Placeholder.vue, but that's not a problem I guess because it's just a placeholder...

Comment: looks like it's really works fine for me. let me clarify something.